# Set up vue js without npm

Tags: npm, vue.js

How can I set up vue js without npm?
I'm not able to install npm right now because of some reasons.
Is vue.js enough? What am I missing?

P.S.: I've just started to learn vue.js and I don't want to miss something and struggle after I realize I need something that I can get only with npm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download the [source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue) and just include it in a script tag in the index.html.

Comment: But what about `vue-cli` or `webpack` or what are those about? I want to have all the features.

Comment: If only npm is the issue you might be able to install via yarn or some other package manager. Other wise you will have to look for each of the source code pages and install manually.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include)?

> Simply download and include with a script tag. Vue will be registered as a global variable.

You can simply use vuejs by including it directly.

Comment: Yes, I did, I just thought there's more that I need to have a full instalation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io). Its an online editor and just got support for Vue. It automates things like transpiling, bundling and dependency management.

- Vue with Router: [Open Editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)
- Simple Vue Example: [Open Editor](https://codesandbox.io/s/7wmm44ko31)

Comment: This setup needs NPM